# Error: Function expected Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a code that doesn't only work in IE. everything works fine on other browsers, the error that occurs in IE is this

```
Line: 11
Error: Function expected
```

this is the fiddle, you can copy paste it as you wish, I really don't know what do. I have no idea why it doesn't work at all
http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/TDWd6/

Code:

```
<form name="formx">
   <input type="text" name="txtMultiplier">
   <input type="button" value="LOOP!" onClick="loop()">
</form>

<script>
function loop(){
    var mynumbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var num = parseInt(document.formx.txtMultiplier.value);

    document.write("Simulating For Loop<br>");
    for(var i = 0; i < mynumbers.length; i++){
        var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
        document.write(mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>");       
    }

    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("Simulating Do While<br>");
    var i = 0;
    do{
       var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
       document.write(mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>");
       i++;    
    }while(i < mynumbers.length);

    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("Simulating While<br>");
    var i = 0;
    while(i < mynumbers.length){
       var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
       document.write(mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>");
       i++;
    }
}
</script>
​
```

Comment: Don't post your code somewhere that may not survive as long as your question. Post the code here so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Not sure why, but `loop` seams to be like some magic name.</s> According to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TDWd6/12/) demo, loop is not a function when clicked. It is a property of `<input type="button"/>` element which calls a loop function. In `onclick` `this` points to an element itself and loop is a property of it equal to 1. That is why it fails with error. Possible fix: change `onclick="loop()"` to `onclick="window.loop()"`

For instance, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TDWd6/7/) it starts working in IE, but `document.write` destroy all previouse DOM/JS and it stops execution after first `document.write` execution.

It will be better if you will use something like on demo below (results are stored in temporary variable which is next passed to `innerHTML` of `res` div):
http://jsfiddle.net/TDWd6/5/

```
function loop1(){
    var mynumbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var num = parseInt(document.formx.txtMultiplier.value);
    var res = "Simulating For Loop<br>";
    for(var i = 0; i < mynumbers.length; i++){
        var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
        res += mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>";
    }

    res += "<br>";

    res += "Simulating Do While<br>";
    var i = 0;
    do{
       var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
       res += mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>";
       i++;    
    }while(i < mynumbers.length);

    res += "<br>";

    res += "Simulating While<br>";
    var i = 0;
    while(i < mynumbers.length){
       var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
       res += mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>";
       i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Also, for some reason, even this code does not work in IE when function name is `loop` (in code and demo above it is called `loop1`). See demo with code like above, but with function called `loop`: http://jsfiddle.net/TDWd6/5/

Comment: what the this thing made me stupid for almost 2 hours!!!... the loop word was just the problem. Any is this word "loop" exist in IE JScript documentation? thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is `document.write`. Internet Explorer doesn't preserve the JavaScript from the document when you destroy it (by implicitly calling `document.open` by calling `document.write` after the DOM is ready), and the functions you call in the loop no longer exist.

Use `createElement` / `createTextNode` / `appendChild` and friends instead of `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

This works in ie9 on my local. But fails on jsfiddle for some reason. Gotta love IE.

```
<form name="formx">
   <input type="text" name="txtMultiplier">
   <input type="button" id="test" value="LOOP!" >
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(){
    loop();
};

function loop(){
    var mynumbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var num = parseInt(document.formx.txtMultiplier.value);

    document.write("Simulating For Loop<br>");
    for(var i = 0; i < mynumbers.length; i++){
        var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
        document.write(mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>");       
    }

    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("Simulating Do While<br>");
    var i = 0;
    do{
       var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
       document.write(mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>");
       i++;    
    }while(i < mynumbers.length);

    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("Simulating While<br>");
    var i = 0;
    while(i < mynumbers.length){
       var prod = num * mynumbers[i];
       document.write(mynumbers[i].toString() + " x " + num.toString() + "=" +  (prod).toString() + "<br>");
       i++;
    }
}
</script>
```